# Separating variables/arrays from an expression, and deleting duplicates?

Tags: java, expression, tokenize

I am separating out variables and array names from an expression, and then trying to delete the duplicates. My code works for most expressions, but I am running into trouble when there is an expression such as `(a + A[a*2-b])`, because my program is recognizing the two `a's` as separate variables due to the space after the first `a`. I feel like there is a simple fix but I cannot figure it out. Any ideas?

```
    public void buildSymbols() {

    String s = expr; //input from a different part of the program 
    scalars = new ArrayList<ScalarSymbol>(5);
    arrays = new ArrayList<ArraySymbol>(5); 

    for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
        if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))){
            String temp = ""; // empty string to add on to

            while(i<s.length() && s.charAt(i)!= '*' && s.charAt(i)!= '/' && s.charAt(i)!= '[' && s.charAt(i)!= ']' && s.charAt(i)!= '+' && s.charAt(i)!= '-' && s.charAt(i)!= '(' && s.charAt(i)!= ')'){ // will form variables until delimiter is found (*/[]())
                temp = temp + s.charAt(i);
                i++;
            }
            if(i<s.length() && s.charAt(i) == '['){ //array 
                ArraySymbol addArr = new ArraySymbol(temp);
                    if(arrays.contains(addArr)){ // duplicate 
                        break;
                    }
                arrays.add(addArr);
            } else{ //variable 
                ScalarSymbol addSca = new ScalarSymbol(temp);
                if(scalars.contains(addSca)){ // duplicate 
                    break;
                }
                scalars.add(addSca);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(arrays);
    System.out.println(scalars);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete the spaces before parsing your expression?

Comment: Deleting the spaces first, or adding a space as a delimiter only gives me the result `a` as a variable, and `A` as an array. Somehow using this method I lose the second variable `b`.

Comment: How about trimming the variable names once you parse that out?

Comment: Same result, still losing the `b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is when you find a variable with the same name you are breaking out of the `for` loop. You should not `break` out of the `for` loop.  Change `break` to `continue` so you can continue parsing through your expression but not add that variable to your list.

```
if(arrays.contains(addArr)){ // duplicate 
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that you have two variables: `"a"` and `"a "`. [String has a nice method called `trim()`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())

So add to your code:

```
temp = temp.trim();
```

and temp will get rid of spaces on either side.

Comment: This gave me the same output as deleting the spaces first, I'm still losing that `b` variable as said in the comments above.